# More computationally efficient way to solve linear system pre-multiplied by the transposed solution

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a linear equation that I am solving:

$Ax = b$, where $A \in C^{n\times n}$ and $B \in C^{n\times m}$ $\&$ $m << n$.

Once I solve for $x \in C^{n \times m}$, I then perform the following calculation:

$y = x^Tx$, where $y \in C^{m \times m}$

As $m << n$ I am wondering if there is an easier (computationally more efficient) way to solve this, that solving the original linear system and then multiplying the two matrices together.

From above, $y$ can also be written as: $y = b^T A^{-T}A^{-1}b$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case of (really) small $m$ can be reduced to the case $m=1$, by considering that, for $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{C}^n$, $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle = \frac{1}{4} ( \lVert x_1+x_2 \rVert^2 - \lVert x_1 - x_2 \rVert ^2) $. That is, we can be more efficient if for the equation $Ax = b$, we can even decide the magnitude of $x$. However, I see no way of doing this more efficiently than with usual solution techniques.